# Can't register variable session (I've search, but nothing help me :(

Tags: php, templates, session

I've got a problem to register variable session. I've ordered my code with MVC (View=Vue in french) modele. Like this : 
[image]

My problem : Index.php include all of others files, so I put the 'session_start();' here. (Anyway I can't put it on other place without taking error log "session has already started")

Firstly index.php 'open' connexion.php, with connexion form for user. When he submit it, my controleur look if it's good, and redirect user to the Accueil.

I would like to register variable 'user' on my controler, but this doesn't work anymore.

My code :

Index.php

```
    <?php session_start();?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fr" lang="fr">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="fr" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Style/style.css" type="text/css" />
<title>Saisie des temps</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id=page>
        <?php
        include_once 'Vues/Header.php';
        ?>
        <div id=corps>
            <?php 
            include_once 'Vues/Menu.php';

            if (!empty($_GET['page']) && 
                    is_file('Controleurs/'.$_GET['page'].'.php')){
                include_once (dirname(__FILE__).'../../SaisieTemps/Controleurs/'.$_GET['page'].'.php');
            }
            else{
                include_once (dirname(__FILE__).'../../SaisieTemps/Controleurs/GestionConnexion/connexion.php');
            }
            ?>
        </div>
        <?php 
        include_once 'Vues/Footer.php';

        ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Controler : COnnexion.php

```
<?php $_SESSION['test']='test'; ==> WORKS BUT TO EARLY ^^

//Inclusion modele
include(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../Modeles/GestionConnexion/Connexion.php');

$login = isset($_POST['username'])?$_POST['username']:'';
$password = isset($_POST['password'])?$_POST['password']:'';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $intError = verifConnexion($login, $password);

    switch ($intError){
        case 0:
            //Connexion OK
            $_SESSION['login']=$login; ==> DOESN'T WORK

            ?><script type="text/javascript">
                document.location.href = '../../../SaisieTemps/index.php?page=GestionConnexion/Accueil';
            </script><?php 
            break;
        case 1:
            //Pb mdp
            ?><script type="text/javascript">
                document.location.href = '../../../SaisieTemps/index.php?page=GestionConnexion/Connexion.php&Error=1';
            </script><?php 
            break;
        case 2:
            //Pb login
            ?><script type="text/javascript">
                document.location.href = '../../../SaisieTemps/index.php?page=GestionConnexion/Connexion.php&Error=2';
            </script><?php 
            break;
        default:
            ?><script type="text/javascript">
                document.location.href = '../../../SaisieTemps/index.php?page=GestionConnexion/Connexion.php&Error=3';
            </script><?php 
            break;
    }
}
else{
    //Inclusion vue
    include(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../Vues/GestionConnexion/Connexion.php');
}
```

View:Connexion.php

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<div id=contenu>
    <form action="../../SaisieTemps/Controleurs/GestionConnexion/Connexion.php" method="POST" id=login>
        <h1>Connexion</h1>
        <fieldset id="inputs">
            <label for="username">Identifiant : </label>
            <input id="username" name="username" type="text"
                placeholder="Identifiant" autofocus required/><br/>   
            <label for="password">Mot de passe : </label>
            <input id="password" name="password" type="password"
                placeholder="Mot de passe"required/>
        </fieldset>
         <fieldset id="actions">
            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Connexion" name="submit">
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <label class="errorLabel"><?php 
            if(isset($_GET['Error'])){
                switch ($_GET['Error']){
                    case 1:
                        echo'Mauvais mot de passe';
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        print'Le login n\'existe pas';
                        break;
                }
            }?>
    </label>
</div>
```

Thank's for your help, and sorry for my bad english

Comment: If you have to post all of your code I have to question how much troubleshooting you have already done

Comment: Have you checked to make sure that `$login` is being set correctly?

Comment: Yes is correctly set. In fact, when I do a var_dump($_SESSION) just after the $_SESSION['login']='blabla';, session appear good, with correctly variables.
But it look like that this variables aren't save.

Comment: @nanis - OK. So they're setting OK - where are you trying to read the values back?

Comment: Thank's to newman, It's works with modification on:
<form action="../../SaisieTemps/Controleurs/GestionConnexion/Connexion.php"

by

<form action="../../SaisieTemps/index.php?page=GestionConnexion/Connexion"

I'm just stupid ^^

Thank's everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your login form action is direct to PHP file (to Controller) not via index.php

And in `Controler : COnnexion.php` session not started.

Change logic of your application or add session_start() to this controller

Comment: I've already try to add a session_start on my conrtoler but I've error message "Session has already been started"

Comment: I've tried to change action form, and it works, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the whitespace before you php code.  It is not allowed to put input before the session_start(); a space or a tab is also seen as content.

Comment: Thank's but it doesn't work anymore (I've restarted wampserver, I've deleted my browser cache, it's the same)